# 3 vectors are on the same line, find p and q.

Tags: vectors

OA(0,2,-3) OB(2,5,-2) OC(3,p,q)
ABC is a straight line, how do I find p and q?
I found AB(2,3,1) BC(1,p-5,q+2) AC(3,p-2,q+3) But I have no idea how to contiue.

Comment: All points lie on $(0,2,-3)+ t ((2,5,-2)-(0,2,-3))$ for some $t$. The first component of $C$ will give you $t$.

Comment: calculate cross product of three vector, if  it is equal to zero, then it is collinear, so find such p and q for which  those will be collinear

Comment: @datodatuashvili Did you mean the scalar triple product of the vectors? Cross products of the three vectors doesn’t really say much about their mutual colinearity. Also, a vanishing triple product isn’t enough by itself to solve this problem since that doesn’t lead to a unique $(p,q)$ pair.

Answer (score 2):

If they are on straight line they follow condition of collinearity which is $AB=\lambda AC$ . Or any other combination you like where $\lambda $ is  a real constant.you have three unknowns equate the corresponding   vectors and get $p,q $

Comment: By AB and AC, do you mean the magnitude?

Comment: vector  not magnitude

Comment: No the coordinates that you have calculated

Comment: Ahhhh, so i find the 'ratio' where I have 2 numbers, and then apply that ratio to find p and q. Ok got it, thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome